# Kendo DatePickerFor Error The value '09-16-2016' is not valid for Date:

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, kendo-ui, datepicker

I am using kendo datePickerFor
Code into model=====

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Date:")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM-dd-yyyy}",
           ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]

    public DateTime TransactionDate { set; get; }
```

Into view page====

```
 @(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m => m.TransactionDate)
                .Format("MM-dd-yyyy")
                .ParseFormats(new List<string>()
                              {
                                "MM-dd-yyyy"
                              })
                )
```

Also use javascript====

```
$(function () {
         kendo.culture("en-US");
    })
```

My kendo DatePickerFor is inside a form.
when I submitting the form giving error - "The value '09-16-2016' is not valid for Date:."
My local machine date format is "dd-MM-yyyy".
When I set this format into datepicker,form submitted correctly.
But I want to set specific format which does no depend on local machine format 
Please know me how to solved this problem.

Comment: You're getting the validation error on client or after posting to server?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you would want to match the cultures on the client and on the server:

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/globalization#match-cultures

The server-side culture can be set, depending on the regional information provided in the browser's request.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Content_negotiation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Language

If there is a valid reason not to do this, then you will have to manually take care of submitting the date value in the correct format, expected by the server.

Comment: Thanks... for feedback

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem - the best description I found (but not a solution) is here: https://blog.gerardbeckerleg.com/posts/kendo-ui-mvc-grid-datepicker-in-line-and-in-cell-edit-validation-error-the-value-is-not-valid/

My local machine culture date format is dd.MM.yyyy, in my multilanguage app I wanted to force always one date format: yyyy-MM-dd, so I added (to never show local date format)

```
@(Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(m => m.TransactionDate)
                .Format("yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

Problem occurred while saving changes only inside kendo grid when I used In-Line edition and only for my local machine culture, which does not allow format with month-first. When I input date in format yyyy-MM-dd, after accepting this change it somehow swapped month and day, and my date 2020-01-05- (january 5th) was saved as 2020-05-01 (may 1st). And when a day was > 12 same error as yours occured (e.g. for date 2020-12-31 - december 31st it couldn't change 31 info a month, and I got error: "The value 31.12.2020 is not valid for Date"
In error messsage a given format was exactly like my local machine culture (dd.MM.yyyy -> 31.12.2020) but error occured so the date was treated as MM.dd.yyyy and in this format 31.12.2020 is not valid indeed.

What was strange I noticed different behaviour when I ran same application from  client machine (but same local culture as mine) and when I was debugging in VS on local machine (on a local machine I couldn't reproduce an error, only on client machine)

What I did?

1. I checked if I load proper kendo culture (I did): kendo.culture("pl-PL");
2. I changed kendo.culture.pl-PL.min.js date format info yyyy-MM-dd. To not change min.js file I did as an extension js method (notice the first true parameter!):

```js
var customCulture = $.extend(true, kendo.culture(), {
            calendars: {
                standard: {
                    patterns: {
                        d: "yyyy-MM-dd",
                        g: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm",
                        G: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        );
```

It forces takes given date formats and pushes (merges) them into currently loaded kendo.culture(), what does the trick. Because I always want to show yyyy-MM-dd format I is what I need.

The idea of solution was taken from here: https://www.telerik.com/forums/calendar-customization-764d6343160b